# How to refresh session values after logined user modify profile

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using Zend_Auth to store session values after login. My question is: let's say the user has changed his email/first name after login, how can I reflect this in the session?

When I do Zend_Auth::getInstance(); after editing the profile it returns the old values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but i think you could use:

```
// fetch data in auth storage
$authStorage = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage();
$authData = $authStorage->read();

// change your values in $authData

$authStorage->write($authData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put Object to Zend_Auth then you can do something like this:

```
$user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
$user->setFoo(bar);
```

And it will be changed (because php pass objects by reference)